# JavaScript + jQuery + Angular: Element is not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a JavaScript function defined. Inside this function, I define variables of type jQuery elements. So, the variables refer to divs on the HTML. This function returns an object that has a single function init().

In the $(document).ready function, I call init() function.

The problem is when the script loads, the DOM is not ready and hence the variables referring to jQuery items are being set to undefined.

Later, I call the init() function inside Angular ngOnInit() to make sure things are well initialized, so nothing is happening as the variables above are undefined and they are not being re-calculated again.

Seems, when a function in JavaScript is defined, its body runs, and hence the variables are run and set to undefined as the HTML elements were not in the DOM yet.

How can I re-calculate the variables when init() runs? I cannot get my mind on this thing.

Thanks

```
var mQuickSidebar = function() {
var topbarAside = $('#m_quick_sidebar');

console.log('Function: ', Date.now());

var topbarAsideTabs = $('#m_quick_sidebar_tabs');    
var topbarAsideClose = $('#m_quick_sidebar_close');
var topbarAsideToggle = $('#m_quick_sidebar_toggle');
var topbarAsideContent = topbarAside.find('.m-quick-sidebar__content');

var initMessages = function() {
    var messenger = $('#m_quick_sidebar_tabs_messenger');  

    if (messenger.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    var messengerMessages = messenger.find('.m-messenger__messages');

    var init = function() {
        var height = topbarAside.outerHeight(true) - 
            topbarAsideTabs.outerHeight(true) - 
            messenger.find('.m-messenger__form').outerHeight(true) - 120;

        // init messages scrollable content
        messengerMessages.css('height', height);
        mApp.initScroller(messengerMessages, {});
    }

    init();        

    // reinit on window resize
    mUtil.addResizeHandler(init);
}

var initSettings = function() { 
    var settings = $('#m_quick_sidebar_tabs_settings');

    if (settings.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // init dropdown tabbable content
    var init = function() {
        var height = mUtil.getViewPort().height - topbarAsideTabs.outerHeight(true) - 60;

        // init settings scrollable content
        settings.css('height', height);
        mApp.initScroller(settings, {});
    }

    init();

    // reinit on window resize
    mUtil.addResizeHandler(init);
}

var initLogs = function() {
    // init dropdown tabbable content
    var logs = $('#m_quick_sidebar_tabs_logs');

    if (logs.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    var init = function() {
        var height = mUtil.getViewPort().height - topbarAsideTabs.outerHeight(true) - 60;

        // init settings scrollable content
        logs.css('height', height);
        mApp.initScroller(logs, {});
    }

    init();

    // reinit on window resize
    mUtil.addResizeHandler(init);
}

var initOffcanvasTabs = function() {
    initMessages();
    initSettings();
    initLogs();
}

var initOffcanvas = function() {
    topbarAside.mOffcanvas({
        class: 'm-quick-sidebar',
        overlay: true,  
        close: topbarAsideClose,
        toggle: topbarAsideToggle
    });   

    // run once on first time dropdown shown
    topbarAside.mOffcanvas().one('afterShow', function() {
        mApp.block(topbarAside);

        setTimeout(function() {
            mApp.unblock(topbarAside);

            topbarAsideContent.removeClass('m--hide');

            initOffcanvasTabs();
        }, 1000);                         
    });
}

return {     
    init: function() { 

        console.log('Inside Init(): ', Date.now());

        console.log($('#m_quick_sidebar')); // topbarAside is undefined here!

        if (topbarAside.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        initOffcanvas(); 
    }
}; }();

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('document.ready: ', Date.now());
    mQuickSidebar.init();
});
```

Comment: Did you try with some timeout  to make everything available on DOM?

Comment: What do you mean please? Can you illustrate more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you immediately invoke your function `mQuickSidebar` not

> Seems, when a function in JavaScript is defined, its body runs

```
var mQuickSidebar = function() {
    var topbarAside = $('#m_quick_sidebar');

    console.log('Function: ', Date.now());

    var topbarAsideTabs = $('#m_quick_sidebar_tabs');    
    var topbarAsideClose = $('#m_quick_sidebar_close');
    var topbarAsideToggle = $('#m_quick_sidebar_toggle');
    var topbarAsideContent = topbarAside.find('.m-quick-sidebar__content');
...
}(); // <---- this runs the function immediately
```

So those var declarations are run and since the DOM is not ready those selectors don't find anything. I'm actually surprised that it does not throw a $ undefined error of some sort

This looks like a broken implementation of [The Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)

I re-wrote your code in the Module Pattern. The changes are small. Keep in mind that everything declared inside the IIFE as a var are private and cannot be accessed through `mQuickSidebar`. Only the `init` function of `mQuickSidebar` is public. I did not know what you needed to be public or private. If you need further clarity just ask.

**As a Module**

```
var mQuickSidebar = (function(mUtil, mApp, $) {

    console.log('Function: ', Date.now());

    var topbarAside;
    var topbarAsideTabs;
    var topbarAsideClose;
    var topbarAsideToggle;
    var topbarAsideContent;

    var initMessages = function() {
        var messenger = $('#m_quick_sidebar_tabs_messenger');  

        if (messenger.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        var messengerMessages = messenger.find('.m-messenger__messages');

        var init = function() {
            var height = topbarAside.outerHeight(true) - 
                topbarAsideTabs.outerHeight(true) - 
                messenger.find('.m-messenger__form').outerHeight(true) - 120;

            // init messages scrollable content
            messengerMessages.css('height', height);
            mApp.initScroller(messengerMessages, {});
        };

        init();        

        // reinit on window resize
        mUtil.addResizeHandler(init);
    };

    var initSettings = function() { 
        var settings = $('#m_quick_sidebar_tabs_settings');

        if (settings.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        // init dropdown tabbable content
        var init = function() {
            var height = mUtil.getViewPort().height - topbarAsideTabs.outerHeight(true) - 60;

            // init settings scrollable content
            settings.css('height', height);
            mApp.initScroller(settings, {});
        };

        init();

        // reinit on window resize
        mUtil.addResizeHandler(init);
    };

    var initLogs = function() {
        // init dropdown tabbable content
        var logs = $('#m_quick_sidebar_tabs_logs');

        if (logs.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        var init = function() {
            var height = mUtil.getViewPort().height - topbarAsideTabs.outerHeight(true) - 60;

            // init settings scrollable content
            logs.css('height', height);
            mApp.initScroller(logs, {});
        };

        init();

        // reinit on window resize
        mUtil.addResizeHandler(init);
    };

    var initOffcanvasTabs = function() {
        initMessages();
        initSettings();
        initLogs();
    };

    var initOffcanvas = function() {
        topbarAside.mOffcanvas({
            class: 'm-quick-sidebar',
            overlay: true,  
            close: topbarAsideClose,
            toggle: topbarAsideToggle
        });   

        // run once on first time dropdown shown
        topbarAside.mOffcanvas().one('afterShow', function() {
            mApp.block(topbarAside);

            setTimeout(function() {
                mApp.unblock(topbarAside);

                topbarAsideContent.removeClass('m--hide');

                initOffcanvasTabs();
            }, 1000);                         
        });
    };

    return {     
        init: function() { 

            console.log('Inside Init(): ', Date.now());

            console.log($('#m_quick_sidebar')); // topbarAside is undefined here!

            topbarAside = $('#m_quick_sidebar');
            topbarAsideTabs = $('#m_quick_sidebar_tabs');    
            topbarAsideClose = $('#m_quick_sidebar_close');
            topbarAsideToggle = $('#m_quick_sidebar_toggle');
            topbarAsideContent = topbarAside.find('.m-quick-sidebar__content');

            if (topbarAside.length === 0) {
                return;
            }

            initOffcanvas(); 
        }
    }; 
})(mUtil, mApp, $);

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('document.ready: ', Date.now());
    mQuickSidebar.init();
});
```

Comment: So I just remove the () not to execute it immediately? Or shall I implement the Module Pattern properly? Thanks

Comment: Added a re-write as a module for you.